# Why get error 500 when I Fetch API in React?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, fetch-api

PHP (build JSOM) I have this:

```php
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $json[] = $row;
}
echo $jsonParsed = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

PHP return: `url..../api.php?action=GET_PRODUCTOS`
Return this if I open in explorer:

```json
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "NOMBRE": "Napolitanas Bimbo",
        "FOTO": "https:\/\/www.tuclubdecompras.es\/contenidos\/articulos\/11\/5790-001-1-2.jpg",
        "PRECIO": "1",
        "DESCRIPCION": "Hojaldres rellenos de crema de cacao\r\n\r\nHARINA DE TRIGO\r\nCREMA DE CACAO (27%)\r\nAROMA\r\nEMULGENTE (LECITINA DE SOJA)\r\nACEITES Y GRASAS VEGETALES (PALMA, GIRASOL)\r\nAZ\u00daCAR\r\nJARABE DE GLUCOSA Y FRUCTOSA\r\nCLARA DE HUEVO\r\nMANTECA DE CERDO\r\nLEVADURA\r\nFIBRA DE AVENA\r\nPROTE\u00cdNA DE LA LECHE\r\nHUEVO\r\nSAL\r\nEMULGENTE (MONO Y DIGLIC\u00c9RIDOS DE \u00c1CIDOS GRASOS VEGETALES)\r\nESTABILIZANTE\r\nCONSERVADOR (SORBATO POT\u00c1SICO)\r\nGLUTEN DE TRIGO\r\n\u00c1CIDO ASC\u00d3RBICO\r\nCOLORANTE (BETA- CAROTENO)"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "NOMBRE": "FLAN ROYAL",
        "FOTO": "https:\/\/www.tuclubdecompras.es\/contenidos\/articulos\/24\/12475-001-1-2.jpg",
        "PRECIO": "2",
        "DESCRIPCION": "HARINA DE TRIGO\r\nCREMA DE CACAO (27%)\r\nAROMA\r\nEMULGENTE (LECITINA DE SOJA)"
    },
    {
        "ID": "3",
        "NOMBRE": "Napolitanas Bimbo",
        "FOTO": "https:\/\/www.tuclubdecompras.es\/contenidos\/articulos\/11\/5790-001-1-2.jpg",
        "PRECIO": "1.5",
        "DESCRIPCION": "Hojaldres rellenos de crema de cacao\r\n\r\nHARINA DE TRIGO\r\nCREMA DE CACAO (27%)\r\nAROMA\r\nEMULGENTE (LECITINA DE SOJA)\r\nACEITES Y GRASAS VEGETALES (PALMA, GIRASOL)\r\nAZ\u00daCAR\r\nJARABE DE GLUCOSA Y FRUCTOSA\r\nCLARA DE HUEVO\r\nMANTECA DE CERDO\r\nLEVADURA\r\nFIBRA DE AVENA\r\nPROTE\u00cdNA DE LA LECHE\r\nHUEVO\r\nSAL\r\nEMULGENTE (MONO Y DIGLIC\u00c9RIDOS DE \u00c1CIDOS GRASOS VEGETALES)\r\nESTABILIZANTE\r\nCONSERVADOR (SORBATO POT\u00c1SICO)\r\nGLUTEN DE TRIGO\r\n\u00c1CIDO ASC\u00d3RBICO\r\nCOLORANTE (BETA- CAROTENO)"
    },
    {
        "ID": "4",
        "NOMBRE": "FLAN ROYAL",
        "FOTO": "https:\/\/www.tuclubdecompras.es\/contenidos\/articulos\/24\/12475-001-1-2.jpg",
        "PRECIO": "2.5",
        "DESCRIPCION": "HARINA DE TRIGO\r\nCREMA DE CACAO (27%)\r\nAROMA\r\nEMULGENTE (LECITINA DE SOJA)"
    }
]
```

But when I call it in a hook give me error 500, why?

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as CONFIG from '../../config.js'

const useProductsQuery = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const url = CONFIG.ACTIONS.getProductos;
        let fetchData = async () => {
            await fetch(url)
            .then(console.log(url))
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => setProducts(json))
            .then(json => console.log(json))
        };
        fetchData();

    }, []);
    return products;
}

export default useProductsQuery;
```

When I open the console, show me error 500 but if I click in Console > Network > Response I see the results!

Comment: Now i test in https://reqbin.com/ and give me Status: 500 (Internal Server Error) but in content i see all info. Whats happens?

Comment: are you able to print the output of your api in the backend server ? plus try to resolve the promise first on response.json() and remove that url console .then

Comment: _`.then(console.log(url))`_  what is this meant to be doing? It will mess up your promise chain completely

Answer (score 0):

not quite an answer but a good start is to remove so of the extra in your hook so we can see whats going on.

Next you'll need to look at the php error logs for that request and post the stacktrace + related code.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as CONFIG from '../../config.js'

const useProductsQuery =  async () => {
  const url = CONFIG.ACTIONS.getProductos
  const res = await fetch(
    url, 
    { // ensure headers are set correctly eg accept json }
  )

  console.log(res, res.json())   
  return res.json()
}

export default useProductsQuery
```